# AWS WAP: How to Whitelist Github Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions

I am using a [blanket rate-based rule on AWS WAP](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/three-most-important-aws-waf-rate-based-rules/), and I need to whitelist github actions.

I can create an ip set with the github actions ip addresses mentioned on their [meta page](https://api.github.com/meta) and then add a statement to the web acl rule to ignore that ip set.

Is this an efficient way to whitelist github actions as there are 2572 ip addresses?

Comment: At the company we work at we use to create a rate-based rule to protect specific URIs at more restrictive rates than the blanket rate-based rule. Because if you release the IPs, it makes room for more general accesses coming from those origins that are not just URIs
.

Comment: I also have a rate-based rule to protect specific URIs with a lower threshold than the blanked rate-based. However, I want to whitelist github actions from the blanked rate-based. It might be a security leak, for instance if someone ddos us from github actions (which I doubt), but we rely on github actions to do some important tasks.

Comment: In that case, I guess you can go with whitelisting all the ip addresses.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked and it didn't slow down anything.